Invalid WebSocket frame: invalid status code 1006
I'm experiencing frequent random disconnections when using the Node.js WebSocket client for Solana. However, I do not encounter this issue when using web3.js. Unfortunately, web3.js does not allow me to change the encoding for the onProgramAccountChange subscription, which is essential for my use case.
Here is the error I'm encountering:
error ErrorEvent {
  target: <ref *1> WebSocket {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      open: [Function (anonymous)],
      close: [Array],
      message: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function]
    },
    _eventsCount: 4,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _binaryType: 'nodebuffer',
    _closeCode: 1002,
    _closeFrameReceived: false,
    _closeFrameSent: false,
    _closeMessage: '',
    _closeTimer: null,
    _extensions: {},
    _protocol: '',
    _readyState: 2,
    _receiver: Receiver {
      _events: [Object],
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _binaryType: 'nodebuffer',
      _extensions: {},
      _isServer: false,
      _maxPayload: 104857600,
      _bufferedBytes: 0,
      _buffers: [],
      _compressed: false,
      _payloadLength: 16,
      _mask: undefined,
      _fragmented: 0,
      _masked: false,
      _fin: true,
      _opcode: 8,
      _totalPayloadLength: 0,
      _messageLength: 0,
      _fragments: [],
      _state: 4,
      _loop: false,
      _eventsCount: 6,
      [Symbol(shapeMode)]: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(websocket)]: [Circular *1]
    },
    _sender: Sender {
      _extensions: {},
      _socket: [TLSSocket],
      _firstFragment: true,
      _compress: false,
      _bufferedBytes: 0,
      _deflating: false,
      _queue: []
    },
    _socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'api.mainnet-beta.solana.com',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 5,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'api.mainnet-beta.solana.com',
      _closeAfterHandlingError: false,
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: null,
      timeout: 0,
      [Symbol(alpncallback)]: null,
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: true,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 1689077,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(shapeMode)]: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: true,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAlive)]: false,
      [Symbol(kSetKeepAliveInitialDelay)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(websocket)]: [Circular *1]
    },
    _bufferedAmount: 0,
    _isServer: false,
    _redirects: 0,
    _url: 'wss://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com',
    _req: null,
    [Symbol(shapeMode)]: false,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  type: 'error',
  message: 'Invalid WebSocket frame: invalid status code 1006',
  error: RangeError: Invalid WebSocket frame: invalid status code 1006
      at Receiver.controlMessage (.../node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:464:18)
      at Receiver.getData (.../node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:350:42)
      at Receiver.startLoop (.../node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:143:22)
      at Receiver._write (.../node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:78:10)
      at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:564:12)
      at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:493:10)
      at Receiver.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:502:10)
      at TLSSocket.socketOnData (.../node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:909:35)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:518:28)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:488:12) {
    [Symbol(status-code)]: 1002
  }
}
Closed to Solana websocket 1002
Reconnecting...
disconnected: 1002 -

Code:
import { Connection } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID } from '@solana/spl-token';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
import WebSocket = require("ws");


const RPC_ENDPOINT = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com";
const WSS_ENDPOINT = "wss://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com";

const connection = new Connection(RPC_ENDPOINT, 'confirmed');

let ws = new WebSocket(WSS_ENDPOINT);

const WssStart = async () => {
  ws = new WebSocket(WSS_ENDPOINT);
  setInterval(()=>ws.ping(() => {}), 15000);

  ws.on("open", () => {
    console.log("Connected to Solana websocket");
    const request = {
      jsonrpc: "2.0",
      id: uuid(),
      method: "programSubscribe",
      params: [
        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID.toString(),
        {
          encoding: "jsonParsed",
          commitment: "confirmed",
        },
      ],
    };
    
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(request));
  });

  ws.on("close", (asd) => {
    console.log("Closed to Solana websocket", asd);
    console.log("Reconnecting...");
    WssStart();
  });

  ws.on('close', function close(code, reason) {
    console.log(`disconnected: ${code} - ${reason}`);
  });


  ws.on("message", async (message) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(message.toString("utf-8"));
    console.log(data)
  });

  ws.onerror = (evt) => {
    console.log('error', evt)
  }

};
WssStart();

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve the frequent disconnections with the Node.js WebSocket client, or how to change the encoding for onProgramAccountChange using web3.js. Thank you!

You have a few options:

Use a different websocket client with reconnecting. Here's the implementation used by web3.js https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/131900beb3cfbc5ebea21e05495c02a63cdb196d/packages/library-legacy/src/rpc-websocket.ts#L14

Add the encoding parameter to https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/131900beb3cfbc5ebea21e05495c02a63cdb196d/packages/library-legacy/src/connection.ts#L6401 -- feel free to submit a PR so that everyone can use it!

Hack the library to hardcode the encoding to whatever you want


